# asp.net core throws 500 even though there are no errors in the action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot a scenario where an asp.net core 2.2 action is returning HTTP 500 to the browser even though there is a matching view that it should return and even though it completes the action all the way to the return View() statement.

Here is the code in the browser, and its that inner POST that I am getting a 500 from the action for despite the fact that a view is returned.

```
$.post({
            url: '/Analysis/SomeOtherAction',
            contentType: dataType,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.IsValid) {
                    if (evaluation === "1") {
                        $.post({
                            url: '/Analysis/WhyDoesThisFail',
                            contentType: dataType,
                            data: JSON.stringify(data)
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location = '/Results/Download?fileGuid=' + response.Data.FileGuid
                            + '&filename=' + response.Data.FileName;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $('#validationList').empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.ValidationMessages.length; i++) {
                        $("#validationList").append("<li>" + response.ValidationMessages[i] + "</li>");
                    }
                    $('#modelValidationModal').modal('toggle');
                }
            }
        });
```

In my controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult WhyDoesThisFail([FromBody] SomeViewModel model)
{
    // some stuff happens in here...

    return View(); // I can step through all the way to this point with no errors
}
```

I want to return the WhyDoesTHisFail View which is in the Analysis folder under VIews.

Comment: First, configure your app to give you the details of the 500 error so you have a better idea of what the real problem is.

Comment: I have app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() in my Starup.cs class.

Comment: Check the output in the VS Output window. Press F12 to check the Developer tool in web browser, share us the response page for the 500 error.